# frame work updgrade for working with tables

Tags: karate

It is posible to create a solution in Karate to access more easy the elements from a table tr ?
For expmple use the ID of a Table to locate, then search for a text in a TD and if is found go up to the TR and do something with other TD from the same TR.

Something like this :
And waitFor("#tableID").contains("text").tr.td(".edit").click()

I know that in Karate are other ways around to do this, but I want to know if it is posible to make it as a feature in karate.

Comment: personally I think this should be a reusable JS function you should write and re-use in your test-suite. start with that, and if it works well, yes you can submit a PR: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#javascript-function-reuse